# Nginx SSL on single subdomain instead of many

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to set SSL for only the "API" subdomain of my site, and here is my config for SSL:

```
# HTTPS server
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name api.example.com;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /some_path/to/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /some_path/to/server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://site;
  }
}
```

However Nginx seems to allow me to connect to https://example.com too. Firefox will then ask me to confirm the same certificate (self-signed by me).

I though using the `server_name` directive will restrict SSL to only that subdomain, but now it allows SSL requests to all of my subdomains too. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), a server serving HTTPS content doesn't know what the domain name being requested is (as the `Host` header is itself encrypted). Thus, all requests to that IP, regardless of domain name, get the default SSL virtual host.

Comment: Thanks, so `server_name` that is not an IP address is ignored in Nginx, making SSL setting a global one.